# Ef code first Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a strange situation

I have 3 entities:

```
public class Product
{
   public virtual int id {get;set;}
}

public class Media
{
   public virtual ICollection<MediaProduct> mediaProducts {get;set;}
}

public class MediaProduct 
{
   public virtual int id {get;set;}
   public virtual Media media {get;set;}
   public virtual Product product {get;set;}

   public virtual int productId { get; set; }
   public virtual int mediaId { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in my product entity I don't have a reference to MediaProduct, and i can't change that.

I dont't know how I can Map those entities.

My class for the mapping is

```
public class MediaProcutMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MediaProduct>
    {
        public MediaProcutMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Media_Product_Mapping");
            this.HasKey(pc => pc.Id);

            this.HasRequired(pc => pc.media)
                .WithMany(c => c.mediaProducts)
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.mediaId);

            //this.HasRequired(pc => pc.product) ???                
        }
    }
```

but it isn't working

please help me

Marco

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of `WithMany` that does not take a parameter.

```
public class MediaProcutMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MediaProduct>
{
        public MediaProcutMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Media_Product_Mapping");
            this.HasKey(pc => pc.Id);

            this.HasRequired(pc => pc.media)
                .WithMany(c => c.mediaProducts)
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.mediaId);

            this.HasRequired(pc => pc.product).
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.productId);              
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Eranga, thanks for your help, but it still give me the same Error: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types

Comment: again thanks for you help, this is my complete error: : 'Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'xxx.MediaProduct' and 'xxx.Product'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.'

Comment: @MarcoLeo Do you have a `MediaProduct` type property in `Product` class? Check whether you have added the mapping correctly.

Comment: How i said in my question I can't modify Product, because it is from other library, for that i am having this problem, what do you think, is this possible or is a Must have the other reference?